# Apache Solr and AWS Comprehend Machine Learning for ordering and categorisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, solr, amazon-machine-learning

This is perhaps more or an architecture question than dev code but appreciate collective thoughts!

We are using Solr to order records and to categorise them to allow users to search and find specific medical conditions. We have an opportunity to make use of Machine Learning to aid and improve the results. AWS Comprehend is the product we are looking at but there is a question over whether one should replace the other as they would compete or if in fact both should work together to provide the solution we are after.

Appreciate any insights people have.

Thanks
Gareth

Comment: Use Elasticsearch in order to get keyword from a request and send this keywords to a machine learning tools seems to be great. Moreover es with kibana will provide you monitoring tools. You read this already? https://www.skedler.com/blog/combine-text-analytics-search-aws-comprehend-elasticsearch-6-0/

Answer (score 0):

Comprehend (Medical, I suppose) lets you extract entities from a text document, and returns a structured JSON document telling you how these entities are related, e.g. medication name+dosage+frequency.

What you could probably do is process documents with Comprehend Medical, and index entities in Solr. This would let you run searches on meaningful structured information instead of full text.